# Is TLS 1.3 available on Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is TLS 1.3 available for an Azure App Service? It came up in a recent security review, but I can't see anything which says this is available.

If it is available, how do I enable this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TLS 1.3 is still not available yet, you could upvote [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6e5f0ef6-c925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c)

[image]

Comment: As rection to recent announcement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment), now TLS 1.2 is the only supported version. What's the delay? Everybody else have had 1.3 for years.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.3 support is coming within 2024:

> TLS 1.3 upcoming support is still planned for the end of 2023 and will continue into 2024. The initial preview support of TLS 1.3 for resources hosted on App Service, namely web apps, functions, and logic apps, began rolling out October 23rd. Users in US regions can expect TLS 1.3 support by January 2024. We will continue to roll-out TLS 1.3 support worldwide and expect to be done sometime early 2024. We will provide another update when TLS 1.3 has been fully rolled out in all regions.
>
> Note: TLS 1.3 will not be supported on App Service Environment (ASE) V1 and V2.

Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/upcoming-tls-1-3-on-azure-app-service-for-web-apps-functions-and/ba-p/3974138